# How to save object to repository depending on its type

Tags: java, spring

I have a controller which receives an object. This object is representing document and this document can be one of some document type.

Depending on document type I should save it to specific repository.

**For example:**

There are 3 document types: `ImageDocument`, `ArticleDocument` and `VideoDocument`.

If controller receives `ImageDocument` it should save it into `ImageDocumentRepository`, If controller receives `ArticleDocument` it should save it into `ArticleDocumentRepository` etc

Which is the best way to implement this logic?

I do not want to autowire all of repositories and creare switch case or if else statements, but nothing else comes to mind

It should be implemented only using java

Comment: in my opinion, the best solution is to create class called CommonDocumentRepositoryManager with method getRepository. getRepository receives document id and depending on it returns suitable repository bean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With just 3 types of documents and 3 repositories, the simplest way is probably to create a `DocumentPersistenceService` which internally has the 3 repositories injected.

You can then use a simple `instance of` check to invoke the right repository according to the type.

If you want to make it more scalable to say 100 document types, you can go for a slightly more complex configuration where you have a `Map` from the class to its respective repository.

So in the constructor of your `DocumentPersistenceService` you could use the Spring `ApplicationContext.getBean()` method to get each repository by name (using your convention, for `ImageDocument` you would do `getBean("ImageDocumentRepository")` and then use the bean you get (assuming its not `null`) to add an entry in your map from `ImageDocument.class` to the `ImageDocumentRepository` reference you get.

When `DocumentPersistenceService` receives the document to save, it can look up the respective repository from the `Map` by the class of the document. The list of documents can actually be provided through configuration, so you don't have to hardcode anything and it can scale to as many as you want.

Answer (score 0):

In general, it is good practice to not have any logic in controller. So in this task I would create some `DocumentService` that has another three (in future you can add more) repositories in it. In this service you can choose in what repo you want to save your document